# How to break signal.pause in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, sigint

I have a main thread which starts child threads and then does signal.pause()

```
def run(self):
    for thread in (some_thread, some_other_thread, another_thread):
        thread.start()

    signal.pause()
```

On completion of work of child threads, the main thread doesn't terminate until it receives SIG_TERM signal.

I can't use join method to wait for child threads to complete since on doing so my program is not listening to external kill signals.

What is the best way to make the main thread come out of signal.pause()?

One way could be to send kill signal from any one of the child threads, but that won't be a good approach.

Comment: What's your rationale for calling `signal.pause()` in the first place?

Comment: you arent joining the threads back to the main thread.. if you want the main thread to wait.. you will need to join the threads back to the main thread.. and have a wait function where it would wait for the signal.pause

Comment: on joining the threads, the process is not listening to kill signals, so I am not able to terminate the process manually.